# facebook post from php through graph api

Tags: php, facebook

i use this code to authorize me with my app

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=myappid&scope=publish_stream,offline_access,manage_pages&method=post&redirect_uri=http://www.site.com/indexold.html

i get the access token and i use this to do the Impersonation trick

https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=myappid&client_secret=myappsecret&redirect_uri=http://www.poemsofloveapp.com/indexold.html

lastly i use this to post to my page ... not the app page but a page i have created
https://graph.facebook.com/mypageid/feed?access_token=1234|asdasdasdasd&message=hello%20world&method=post

the post is successful but it is shown as i have posted it . i want the profile picture of the group to be shown next to the post is this possible? instead mine is shown next to the post!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called `impersonation` in facebook graph api terminology.

Check [here](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&biw=1440&bih=770&sa=X&ei=g_rYTbW6EYfRrQfF-4DvBQ&ved=0CBkQvwUoAQ&q=facebook+graph+api+page+impersonation&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=3897923a35f9f5e8)

And, also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309154/update-facebook-page-status-from-that-page-itself-graph-api-php)