# Facebook: Post on Page as Page issue (access token / php)

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

I'm totally frustrated with my first facebook app project. I'm having major issues with what seems to be a simple task.

I want to setup a cron job on my server (easy) that will post something smart on a facebook page (not my profile), and it should be posted as page. I coded myself into a corner and am totally confused now... Can anyone help, please?

I've been thru pretty much every error message and am now stuck on
"**OAuthException: Error validating application.**"

Here's what I have now:

First php -> Gets a new Access Token for my page access. This part seems to work fine, as I get the next page called and receive a new access token.

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "1234....";
$app_secret = "5678....";
$my_url = "http://.../next.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true
));

// known valid access token stored in a database
$access_token = "abc....";

$code = $_REQUEST["code"];

// If we get a code, it means that we have re-authed the user
//and can get a valid access_token.
if (isset($code)) {
    $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
client_id="
      . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
      . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
      . "&code=" . $code . "&display=popup";
    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $access_token = $params['access_token'];

}

// Attempt to query the graph:
$graph_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/me?"
    . "access_token=" . $access_token;
$response = curl_get_file_contents($graph_url);
$decoded_response = json_decode($response);

//Check for errors
if ($decoded_response->error) {
  // check to see if this is an oAuth error:
  if ($decoded_response->error->type== "OAuthException") {
      // Retrieving a valid access token.
      $dialog_url= "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?"
        . "client_id=" . $app_id
        . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url);
      echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $dialog_url
      . "'</script>");
  } else {
      echo "other error has happened";
    }
} else {

  // success
    echo("success" . $decoded_response->name);

}

function curl_get_file_contents($URL) {
    $c = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $URL);
    $contents = curl_exec($c);
    $err  = curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($c);
    if ($contents) return $contents;
    else return FALSE;
}

?>
```

Next php -> Read the access token and post on the wall. I get the access token from my query string, but then why do I receive the error message. My id, secret and page id are all in order...

```
<?php
require_once 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "1234....";
$app_secret = "5678....";
$page_id = "0909....";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true
));

$access_token = $_GET['code'];
echo($access_token);

try {
    $attachment = array(
                'access_token' => $access_token,
                'message'=> "Hello World"
        );

    $result = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed','POST',
$attachment);
    var_dump($result);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}

?>
```

I'm sure there is a simpler way to do so.... and a way to actually make it work!
Any help is appreciated!

I followed this script
[Update facebook page status from that page itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309154/update-facebook-page-status-from-that-page-itself-graph-api-php)
and this
https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500

Thank you.

Comment: I'm unclear in your code (not a PHP dev myself) as to where you are extracting the page access token like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4309154/update-facebook-page-status-from-that-page-itself-graph-api-php does.

Comment: I'm getting the access token in the first script, because, when I use the access token acquired from the example you linked to, the token is limited for 2 hours. The first script checks the old access token -> realizes that it's old -> and returns me a new one in the query string...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it appears you are not getting a PAGE access token which you need, but instead you're using a USER access token, hence why the API doesn't like it.  For more information on how to get a PAGE access token from a USER one, please see the **Page login** section of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The access token concept makes me feel really stupid. Somehow I can't get my head around it... :/  Anyway, I'll check it out again and (hopefully) post a working code soon...

Comment: Yes, it will take time to wrap your head around it. It literally took me three development days to get to a point where I could use it.  Happy Coding.  I hope my answer helped you.

Comment: Thanks for your input, DMCS. I've got it to work (see answer below), though it's far from perfect.

Comment: I did not mean any disrespect. Yes, I corrected the page access token issue thanks to your response. And unfortunately I can't Up Vote answers since I don't have enough reputation points.
Anyway, I wanted to post the entire code for anyone who might be interested. Shouldn't I post it as an new answer then?

Comment: Where you have the code is fine, but you can always edit your question itself and post the entire code if you want and mark it that this is what you came up with based on my help.  Thanks for the accept on the answer.  :)  Happy coding!

Answer (score 6):

```
// firstly include the fb sdk 

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId'  => 'your app id',
                'secret' => 'your app secret',`enter code here`
                'cookie' => true,

    ));


$session = $facebook->getUser();
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
                    array(
                        'scope' => 'user_status,publish_stream,email,user_location,user_birthday,friends_birthday,manage_pages',
                        'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.example.com/'
                    )
                );

    $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl(
                    array(
                        // any url u want to redirsct onto   
                        'redirect_uri' => 'http://www.example.com/'

                    )
                );

// when redirected from facebook get the code 
    $code = $_GET['code'];

// 

                                        $my_url     = 'http://www.example.com/';

                                        $app_id     = 'your app id ';
                                        $app_secret = 'your app secret ';
                                        // here we have the access token so we will play with it 
                                        if (isset($code)) {
                                                $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
                                                  . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) 
                                                  . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
                                                  . "&code=" . $code ;
                                                $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
                                                $params = null;
                                                parse_str($response, $params);
                                                $user_access_token = $params['access_token'];
                                          }

// here we got the access token of user over here in $user_access_token
// now we will get for our page
//------ get PAGE access token
                                        $attachment_1 = array(
                                            'access_token' => $user_access_token
                                        );
                                        $page_id = 'your page id ';
                                        $result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts", $attachment_1);
                                            foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
                                                if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
                                                    $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
                                                    break;
                                                }
                                            }

                                        //          write to page wall
                                        try {
                                            $attachment = array(
                                                        'access_token' => $page_access_token,
                                                        'message'=> 'hello world posting like admin!',
                                                        'page_id'=> $page_id
                                                );

                                             $result = $facebook->api('/'.$page_id.'/feed','POST',$attachment);
                                            //$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed','POST', $attachment);
                                            var_dump($result);

                                        } catch(Exception $e) {
                                            echo $e;
                                        }
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the code and comments give a great example of how to properly use the SDK. SO needs an option to favorite answers.

Answer (score -1):

After many hours of trial and error, here's my solution that works so far.

```
<?php

require_once 'facebook.php';

//------ vars
$app_id = "123...";
$app_secret = "abc..."; 
$page_id = "999...";
$my_url = "http://exactly the same as defined /";

//------ fb object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true
));

//------ verification CODE
// this is not pretty -> the code should be received with a another graph query...
// but I couldn't get this to work. Thus I'm using my last known Verification Code
$code = "ABC123...";

//------ get USER access token
if (isset($code)) {
    $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $app_id 
        . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
        . "&code=" . $code 
        . "&redirect_uri=" . $my_url;

    $response = file_get_contents($token_url);
    $params = null;
    parse_str($response, $params);
    $user_access_token = $params['access_token'];

} else {
    echo("No code");
}

//------ get PAGE access token
$attachment_1 = array(
    'access_token' => $user_access_token
);

$result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts", $attachment_1);
    foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
        if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
            $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
            break;
        }
    }

//------ write to page wall
try {
    $attachment = array(
                'access_token' => $page_access_token,
                'message'=> 'hello world!'
        );

    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed','POST', $attachment);
    var_dump($result);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e;
}

?>
```

Comment: Dude, that's not nice.  DMCS gave you the correct answer, and you stole it from him/her. -1 on your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I obviously don't quite understand how the stackoverflow rating and accepting works. I marked this answer with the check mark since this contains the entire solution. Obviously DMCS contributed to a great part to this. So how should I've done? Or better yet, how can I change to make it correct?

Comment: You got it.  That gray check mark is kinda hard to figure out at first.