# Programmatically post a facebook page status using Cron with the PHP API

Tags: php, facebook, api, cron

So I have been tearing my hair out trying to make this work. I have been all over stack overflow looking at existing questions and found this: [Facebook: Post on Page as Page issue (access token / php)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9066474/facebook-post-on-page-as-page-issue-access-token-php) but it still doesn't seem to solve my problem.

I'm trying to post to my facebook page every day using a cron job. I am having problems with the authentication. Here's my code:

```
    //Post to Facebook
//Variables
$app_id = "...";
$app_secret = "..."; 
$page_id = "...";
$my_url = "http://.../";
$access_token = "taken from page access token (developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/)";

//Create the facebook object
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
 'appId' => $app_id,
 'secret' => $app_secret,
 'cookie' => true
));

//Get the access token using Facebook Graph API
//This gives permission to post to the wall
$token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id=" . $app_id 
    . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret 
    . "&code=" . $access_token 
    . "&redirect_uri=" . $my_url;

$response = file_get_contents($token_url);
$params = null;
parse_str($response, $params);
$user_access_token = $params['access_token'];


//Get a list of pages and loop through
//If one matches one in the variables above, that's the one
//We're posting to
$attachment_1 = array(
    'access_token' => $user_access_token
);

$result = $facebook->api("/me/accounts", $attachment_1);
    foreach($result["data"] as $page) {
        if($page["id"] == $page_id) {
            $page_access_token = $page["access_token"];
            break;
        }
    }

//Write to the Page wall
try {
    $attachment = array(
                'access_token' => $page_access_token,
                'message'=> "Hello World"
        );

    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed','POST', $attachment);

} catch(Exception $e) {
    //Send me an email
    ...
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

This works if I access the script in a browser (I assume it is using my facebook session then), but not when it is triggered by the cron job.

I would really appreciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Get the access token using Facebook Graph API
//This gives permission to post to the wall
```

If you already have a page access token, then this step is wrong at this point – it’s for exchanging the code that the Auth dialog passes back to your app for a user access token.

But since you already have your page access token, you can skip that step (everything from the above comments up to `//Write to the Page wall`).

All you have to do, is to use your page access token in your API call, instead of the user access token you are giving there right now.

Comment: Thank you so much, that fixed it. You sir, are a genius :) Out of interest, how long does it take to feel confident with these APIs? The documentation seems confusing to me.

Comment: Also, I see this now goes through the Graph API instead of my Application. If I wanted to, how could I change my solution to work through my facebook app? Many thanks.

Comment: _“this now goes through the Graph API instead of my Application”_ – I’m not sure I understand what you mean by that. Do you mean, that the postings appear to have been made by the page itself, instead of an actual user? That’s supposed to be like that. If you want to post as a user, you’d still have to get a user access token, not a page access token.